# How can I ignore bulk load data conversion error (truncation)

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, truncation, longtext

I have a file that is an extract from a MySQL table that I would like to in turn load to a SQL table (csv file) through a SSMS job.  However, there is a field in the file that is defined as "LONGTEXT", which is way too long for a SQL table.  I'd like to use BULK INSERT to load the file, but as expected, I'm getting an error "bulk load data conversion error (truncation)" on the "LONGTEXT" field.  I don't mind truncating the field, so that I can get it loaded, but don't know how to ignore that specific error.  Any ideas how to address this?

thanks so much in advance!

Comment: what is the size of the column you are inserting it into?

Answer (score 0):

Given what you said there are two ways to fix the problem.

- Make the column bigger in the table you are inserting the data
- Make the data smaller in the CSV file.

If you can't do one of those two things then you can't use BULK INSERT without getting the error.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I'm unable to ask the vendor to trim the field down.  I can't increase the column in SQL, as the field can contain 4,294,967,295 characters.  I can't even resolve this through a SSIS package that I know of.  Any ideas how I can make the data smaller in that field?

Comment: Never mind, I was able to resolve this in my SSIS package.  Thank you!

Comment: @Henry -- that should be able to fit in a varchar(max) these days